# Why doesn't the variable increment itself?

Tags: c, logical-operators, logical-or, logical-and

I am having trouble understanding this piece of code here. My question is why doesn't the post-increment work on the variable j? Seems like the line never gets executed and it ends up printing 0 0 instead of 0 1?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    (i == 0) || j++;
    printf("%d %d", i, j);
}
```

I would appreciate if someone explained to me where I'm wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

The second operand of the logical OR operator is not evaluated if the first operand (sub-expression) yields true.

In this expression

```
(i == 0) || j++;
```

`i == 0` is true so the second operand `j++` is not evaluated.

If you will rewrite the expression like

```
(i == 0) && j++;
```

then the second operand (sub-expression) will be evaluated.

From the C Standard (6.5.13 Logical AND operator)

> 4 Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
>   a sequence point between the evaluations of the ﬁrst and second
>   operands. **If the ﬁrst operand compares equal to 0, the second operand
>   is not evaluated.**

and (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 4 Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
>   a sequence point between the evaluations of the ﬁrst and second
>   operands. **If the ﬁrst operand compares unequal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.**

Comment: aka `Lazy evaluation`

Answer (score 2):

`(i == 0)` evaluates to `1`, so the result of the `||` is `1`. It doesn't execute the `j++` in this case. If it was `(i == 1) || j++;` instead, for instance, then `j` would be increased.

This is explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical):

> There is a sequence point after the evaluation of lhs. If the result
>   of lhs compares unequal to zero, then rhs is not evaluated at all
>   (so-called short-circuit evaluation)

Comment: Thank you for linking the detailed explanation!